# Is it possible to overload classes with C++20?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Is it possible to overload classes with concepts with C++20 ? I just tried this and it doesn't work.

```
template<typename StringT>
    requires requires( StringT t )
    {
        { t } -> same_as<string>;
    }
struct S
{
};

template<typename StringT>
    requires requires( StringT t )
    {
        { t } -> same_as<wstring>;
    }
struct S
{
};
```

Comment: As always elaborate _"doesn't work"_ please!

Comment: No, there cannot be multiple classes with the same name.

Comment: @Quimby: There is, with enable_if, but that's very clumsy.

Comment: @BonitaMontero: No, not even with `enable_if`.

Comment: What are we talking about? A template class and that is what we are talking about, can have multiple instantiations. And it can be done by simple specialization, SFINAE and concepts as well. So what is the sense of writing "no" here?

Comment: @Klaus: Because none of that is "overloading".

Comment: @NicolBolas: I fully agree that it is wrong wording. But OP posts a template class so why such comments? Quite clear that we talk about templates... isn't it? That a template specialization is not called overload... ok, but give comments with "NO"? Sorry... Feels not helpful and not in the sense of SO!

Comment: @Klaus But there is not specialization in the question. Sorry for assuming that OP meant overload when they said "overload" and made an example with two definitions with the same name. From the one answer posted, specialization is not what OP wants apparently.

Comment: @BonitaMontero No, be careful about that, it is undefined behaviour if the program contains two classes with the same name but different definition and the compiler is not required to report that.

Comment: @Quimby: If concepts is in play, we know that we are talking about templates and the three general types generating "specialized" instances by specialization, SFINAE or concepts. The thing I did not agree is that we can see what was meant ( by using concepts ) and give the totally wrong answer only because a single word was wrong in the question. A hint to the wrong word is what is needed, not the wrong answer. My two cents

Answer (score 9):

You can't overload the class, but you can specialize it since it is a template.

You may think it's just another name for the same thing, but the distinction is subtly important. Overloading means having multiple definitions attached to the same name. Each instantiation of a struct template creates a new name, so "overloading" is not what's going on here.

The typical way to do what you want is to create an undefined declaration for your struct, and then provide specializations as needed.

Taking your code as-is, it would look like:

```
#include <string>
#include <concepts>

using namespace std;

template<typename T>
struct S;

template<typename StringT>
    requires requires( StringT t )
    {
        { t } -> same_as<string>;
    }
struct S<StringT>
{
};

template<typename StringT>
    requires requires( StringT t )
    {
        { t } -> same_as<wstring>;
    }
struct S<StringT>
{
};
```

However, if you are only going to use a `std::same_as`, you might as well just specialize on the type directly:

```
#include <string>

template<typename T>
struct S;

template<>
struct S<std::string>
{
};

template<>
struct S<std::wstring>
{
};
```

Comment: That was just an example. I'm in a special case where I need concepts.

Comment: @BonitaMontero That's why I've put both: The answer to the question you asked, and the ideal solution for the code you posted, in case someone else lands here.

Comment: @BonitaMontero then perhaps you should ask about your actual situation.